# Web app Google sign-in

Tags: javascript, html, google-signin

I am integrating google sign-in in my web app. I followed the instructions from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). But I am unable to get any user information from the sign-in. The sign-in button works perfectly fine though.

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="3*****-c*******************.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<div class="g-signin2 googleSignIn" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

I use these javascript functions:

```
if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
        var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
        email=profile.getEmail();
        }
    }
```

This function results in an error: auth2 is not defined.
If I use `window.onLoadCallback = function()` before the function then it gives no error but also nothing in the log. If I use only this instead:

```
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("done");
    }
```

again I get no error but also nothing in the console log.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code before if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) it. Try to run it.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init();

    // Sign the user in, and then retrieve their ID.
    auth2.signIn().then(function () {
        console.log(auth2.currentUser.get().getId());
    });
});
```

Comment: This error is coming now : `Uncaught Object {error: "popup_closed_by_user"}`
I don't close any pop up window. The error comes as soon as a popup window appears to sign in to my account after clicking the google sign in button. If I am already signed in then the error comes as soon as I load the page.

Comment: Hey! It works if I allow pop-ups. But the user's browser won't enable this by default. And now the sign-in pop up comes as soon as the page loads without clicking the sign in button.

Comment: Calling `auth2.signIn()` will either load the current session or pop up the select account screen if there doesn't exist a session by desgin.  You can check if a session exists before calling signIn() to avoid the popup: `if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()){ auth2.signIn(); }`.  That is, load the session if it exists, otherwise, delay calling `signIn()` until necessary.